# How to run a SQL script in MongoDb

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, robo3t

Hello i have an SQl Script which was meant originally for MySQL. I am going to use Mongodb because it's free. Under MySQL Workbench i had to go to File -> Run Script and that was ist. How it is done in MongoDb/3T Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all [**MySQL is free** and open-source software under the terms of the GNU General Public License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).

Second you should to [choose database solution](https://yalantis.com/blog/how-to-choose-a-database/) according your project needs

Third MongoDB is NoSQL databse, so you can not run SQL script, you can use JavaScript instead.